# iOS Maps UIPopover misplaced after orientation change

Tags: ios, ipad, maps, orientation, uipopovercontroller

we are working on a tablet app and have the following problem:

We are using popover controllers if the user touches a pin on the map but after orientation change, the popover is misplaced. But we cannot keep a reference because after orientation change, the pins are reloaded.

Did someone already have this problem and found a generic solution for this? I wonder how apple is handling this.

Generally the placement of popovers after orientation change is sometimes acting a bit strange.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is closing the popover after rotation. Unfortunately there's not going to be much you can do that wouldn't require some complicated repositioning logic. Perhaps store the origin point as an iVar and calculate the new coordinates based on the new orientation. There's no generic solution for this, however.

Comment: Hm i really wonder how apple is doing this in the maps app - very smooth transition on orientation changes

Comment: When you present the popover you could capture information from the annotation view you are presenting from. On rotation, you could compare this stored information to the current annotation views to determine the new pin.